# RStudio keyboard shortcut for adding another cursor not working

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio

I want to add a second cursor in RStudio editor to edit a couple of line at once. I'm trying to use the key combination CTRL+ALT+Up or Down, as explained [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/05/06/rstudio-v0-99-preview-more-editor-enhancements/). But this is not working.

Is there another combination that should be used in Linux / Ubuntu?
I'm using RStudio Version 1.2.1335 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus).

Comment: Same going on with me.  I'm with RStudio 1.2.1335 as well and Lubuntu 19.04. I think your question should include the ubuntu version (and perhaps flavor) you're using. It would be useful to those trying to answer it.